# Office.js Excel: Format and write to visible cel

Tags: office-js, excel-2016

Is there a way to format Excel.RangeView? like not only set values but change the background colour, etc.? I'm using this code to set the same value to all the cells and need to highlight them with red color

```
const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange().getVisibleView();
range.load(['rowCount', 'columnCount']);
await context.sync();

range.set({
  values: Array(range.rowCount)
    .fill(0)
    .map(() =>
      Array(range.columnCount)
        .fill(0)
        .map(() => value)
    ),
  // TODO: investigate why this is not working:
  // format: {
  //    font: {
  //        color: 'red',
  //    },
  // },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting Range and RangeView objects mixed up. The variable that you call `range` is actually a RangeView object. `RangeView.set` can only set properties of RangeView. The RangeView object does not have a `format` property. Try converting the RangeView to a Range with `Worksheet.getRange(myRangeView.cellAddresses)`.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, i think you want to change the background color of the range and font color, therefore you could use the following API

range.format.fill.color

range.format.font.color

```
    range.format.fill.color = "#4472C4";
    range.format.font.color = "white";
```

More information can be found at this url:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.rangefill?view=office-js